# I have difficulties writing code for this assignment for if/else statement. This is first programming class

Tags: c++, if-statement

Write a program that calculates the areas of 2 triangles. Ask the user for the base and height of each triangle. Print the areas of both triangles. The program should tell the user which triangle has the larger area, or if the areas are the same. ERROR CHECKING: The user should not be allowed to enter a negative number for base or height, so validate the input.

This is what I have done so far but, my program does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    double  baseOne, baseTwo, heightOne, heightTwo, areaOne, areaTwo, i1;

    cout << "Please enter the base and height of first triangle\n";

    cin >> baseOne, heightOne;

    if (baseOne <= 0 && heightOne <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Your value is invalid!!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "What is the length of first triangle?\n";
        cin >> baseOne, heightOne;
        areaOne = (baseOne * heightOne) / 2;

        cout << "Area of the first triangle is" << areaOne << endl;

    }
    cout << "What is the base and height of second triangle\n";

    cin >> baseTwo, heightTwo;

    if (baseTwo <= 0 && heightTwo <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Your value is invalid!!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "What is the length of first triangle?\n";
        cin >> baseTwo, heightTwo;
        areaTwo = (baseTwo * heightTwo) / 2;

        cout << "Area of the first triangle is" << areaTwo << endl;

    }

    if (areaOne > areaTwo)
    {
        cout << "Area One is larger with " << areaOne << "than area two\n";
    }
    else if (areaOne < areaTwo)
    {
        cout << "Area Two is larger with" << areaTwo << "than area one\n";

    }

    else
        areaOne == areaTwo;
    areaOne = i1;
    cout << "Magnitude of area one and area two is same with " << i1 <<< endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when yuo try to compile it?

Comment: For second triangle, I had to cout << "What is base and height of second triangle? and cout << area of second triangle is; this will not impact a lot in the program, my main concern is to learn how to use if/else statements properly. This is the error message:

Comment: What's the point of `else areaOne == areaTwo;`? If you get to that `else` block, they have to be equal, since the first two `if` conditions check `>` and `<`. And why do you have a comparison as a statement? That doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: This isn't how you read two values: `cin >> baseOne, heightOne;` It should be `cin >> baseOne >> heightOne;`

Comment: If the user enters invalid input, you need to ask for it again after printing the error. Instead you ask for it again in the `else` block, even though they gave correct input.

Comment: Why does the second question ask for the length of the triangle instead of base and height?

Comment: You have a typo: `<<< endl` should be `<< endl`. Anyway, read your compiler warnings, they should help you understand many of your problems.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'i1' used Project13 c:\users\rable\source\repos\project13\project13\why.cpp 56 
Warning C4553 '==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='? Project13 c:\users\rable\source\repos\project13\project13\why.cpp 55 
Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'heightOne' used Project13 c:\users\rable\source\repos\project13\project13\why.cpp 13 
Error C4700 uninitialized local variable 'heightTwo' used Project13 c:\users\rable\source\repos\project13\project13\why.cpp 30

Comment: What is `areaOne = i1;` supposed to do when you never assigned anything to `i1`? You have lots of really basic syntax errors, go back to your textbook.

Comment: I am trying to edit and recompile again.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the warnings/error the compiler gave you, then you could have easily figured out what the problems are. I see the following problems with your code :

1. `areaOne == areaTwo;` I think what you wanted to do was `areaOne =
   areaTwo;`The former is a check to see if `areaOne` is equal to
   `areaTwo` whereas the latter is assigning the value of `areaTwo` to
   `areaOne`.
2. Typo at `cout << "Magnitude of area one and area two is same with "
   << i1 << < endl;` The extra `<` is not needed.
3. To take two inputs, you should use `cin >> baseOne >> heightOne;` instead of `cin >> baseOne, heightOne;` Similarly for `cin >> baseTwo >> HeightTwo`
4. `double i1`  is declared at line 7, but is never initialized, you straight away use it as `areaOne = i1;` at line 56. That is wrong, initialize it first before you think about using it.

Answer (score 0):

1. cout << "Magnitude of area one and area two is same with "<< i1 << < endl; extra <
2. Incorrect syntax for cin, should be cin>>a>>b;
3. You need to use OR in place of AND in if, what if one of the values was negative

Correct implementation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    double  baseOne, baseTwo, heightOne, heightTwo, areaOne, areaTwo, i1;

    cout << "Please enter the base and height of first triangle\n";

    cin >> baseOne>> heightOne;

    if (baseOne <= 0 || heightOne <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Your value is invalid!!\nEnter again";
        cin >> baseOne>> heightOne;
    }
    else
    {
        areaOne = (baseOne * heightOne) / 2;

        cout << "Area of the first triangle is" << areaOne << endl;

    }
    cout << "What is the base and height of second triangle\n";

    cin >> baseTwo>> heightTwo;

    if (baseTwo <= 0 || heightTwo <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Your value is invalid!!\nEnter again";
        cin >> baseTwo>> heightTwo;
    }
    else
    {
        areaTwo = (baseTwo * heightTwo) / 2;

        cout << "Area of the second triangle is" << areaTwo << endl;

    }

    if (areaOne > areaTwo)
    {
        cout << "Area One is larger than area two\n";
    }
    else if (areaOne < areaTwo)
    {
        cout << "Area Two is larger than area one\n";

    }

    else
    cout << "Magnitude of area one and area two is same ";

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```